# How to code for a raspberry Pi in windows?

Tags: python, vs-code

I know this question has been asked before, but I couldnt find any way for pycharm...

I want to code on my windows pc with librarys which are only available for the raspberry pi and deploy it afterwards on the raspberry.

Is there a way with pycharm or should I use vscode?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the language you want to code the Pi in and possibly the size of your projects as well (small projects can be coded directly on the pi using e.g. VNC).

Comment: Python is already well suited to this task since its a scripting language, you just need to make sure you install the same python packages on the pi that you have to install on your windows box. Then the other major thing to concider is if your program needs to interface with the pi hardware. If your making a robot that uses the GPIO or your program needs to do direct system calls, then this gets harder to devolop on a different OS and different hardware.  If your program is just analizing data, or scraping the web, then it probably will work on both systems pretty well.